# How do I take a list and print all of the content in a random order, printing each exactly one time in python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, for-loop, random

This is what I have:

```
>>> import random
>>> chars = [1, 6, 7, 8, 5.6, 3]
>>> for k in range(1, len(chars)+1):
...   print random.choice(chars)
...   chars[random.choice(chars)] = ''
...
```

But when I run it,

```
5.6
1

5.6

8
>>>
```

I don't want it to print a random amount of each one, I want it to print all of the content once, in a random order. And why is it printing spaces?

Comment: You want `random.shuffle`. See the docs: http://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html#random.shuffle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a working version of your code.

```
import random
chars = [1, 6, 7, 8, 5.6, 3]
for k in range(1, len(chars)+1):
    thechar = random.choice(chars)
    place = chars.index(thechar)
    print thechar
    chars[place:place+1]=''
```

When you do the random.choice twice in `print random.choice(chars)` and in `chars[random.choice(chars)] = ''`, it is picking another random choice from `chars`. Instead, set the `random.choice` to something so that you can call it later. Even if you had done that, when you set `chars[random.choice(chars)] = ''`, it just sets that spot to `''`, it doesn't delete it. So if your `random.choice` was `5.6`, the `chars` list would just become `[1, 6, 7, 8, '', 3]`, not `[1, 6, 7, 8, 3]`. To do that, you have to save the place of the char, and do `chars[place:place+1]`. And finally, due to the `for` syntax, you have to do the `len(chars)+1`, so that it only goes to `len(chars)`.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
import random
chars = [1, 6, 7, 8, 5.6, 3]
r = chars [:] #make a copy in order to leave chars untouched
random.shuffle (r) #shuffles r in place
print (r)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import random
chars = ['s', 'p', 'a', 'm']

random.shuffle(chars)
for char in chars:
    print char
```

This will randomize the list in-place though.

Answer (score 1):

```
list = [1, 6, 7]
random.shuffle(list)
for k in range(1,len(list)+1):
    print list[k]
```

Answer (score 0):

See the following link:
    [Shuffle and re shuffle list in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21337456/shuffle-and-re-shuffle-list-in-python/21338285#21338285)

```
from random import shuffle

x = [[i] for i in range(10)]
shuffle(x)

print x
```