# Inverse of random.shuffle()?

Tags: python, python-3.x, random

I have a function, for simplicity I'll call it shuffler and it takes an list, gives random a seed 17 and then prints that list shuffled.

```
def shuffler( n ):
   import random
   random.seed( 17 )
   print( random.shuffle( n ) )
```

How would I create another function called unshuffler that "unshuffles" that list that is returned by shuffler(), bringing it back to the list I inputted into shuffler() assuming that I know the seed?

Comment: What shuffling algorithm is being used?  You need to dig into the guts of the shuffle to reverse it.  Alternatively save an unshuffled copy of the array, or is that cheating?

Comment: Yeah that's cheating. I have no idea how to do it though...

Comment: I need to be able to take any shuffled list that I know the seed of, and unshuffle it

Comment: I think you may find the answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4557444/python-random-sequence-with-seed

Answer (score 8):

Just wanted to contribute an answer that's more compatible with functional patterns commonly used with numpy. Ultimately this solution should perform the fastest as it will take advantage of numpy's internal optimizations, which themselves can be further optimized via the use of projects like [numba](http://numba.pydata.org/). It ought to be *much* faster than using conventional loop structures in python.

```python
import numpy as np

original_data = np.array([23, 44, 55, 19, 500, 201]) # Some random numbers to represent the original data to be shuffled
data_length = original_data.shape[0]

# Here we create an array of shuffled indices
shuf_order = np.arange(data_length)
np.random.shuffle(shuf_order)

shuffled_data = original_data[shuf_order] # Shuffle the original data

# Create an inverse of the shuffled index array (to reverse the shuffling operation, or to "unshuffle")
unshuf_order = np.zeros_like(shuf_order)
unshuf_order[shuf_order] = np.arange(data_length)

unshuffled_data = shuffled_data[unshuf_order] # Unshuffle the shuffled data

print(f"original_data: {original_data}")
print(f"shuffled_data: {shuffled_data}")
print(f"unshuffled_data: {unshuffled_data}")

assert np.all(np.equal(unshuffled_data, original_data))
```

Comment: How would you do this in a faster way for a 2D array ? (for an image for instance with up to 20M elements)

Answer (score 3):

Here are two functions that do what you need:

```
import random
import numpy as np

def shuffle_forward(l):
    order = range(len(l)); random.shuffle(order)
    return list(np.array(l)[order]), order

def shuffle_backward(l, order):
    l_out = [0] * len(l)
    for i, j in enumerate(order):
        l_out[j] = l[i]
    return l_out
```

**Example**

```
l = range(10000); random.shuffle(l)
l_shuf, order = shuffle_forward(l)
l_unshuffled  = shuffle_backward(l_shuf, order)

print l == l_unshuffled
#True
```

Answer (score 2):

Reseed the random generator with the seed in question and then shuffle the list 1, 2, ..., n. This tells you exactly what ended up where in the shuffle.

Comment: but is there an inverse I can use as the string that will do the opposite?

Comment: The shuffled indices tell you where the nth item has to go in the unshuffled list. I.e. Unshuffled[ShuffledIndex[i]] = Shuffled[i]. Alternatively, you can build an inverse index from that list like so: InverseIndex[ShuffledIndex[i]] = i. This lets you retrieve the original item i as Shuffled[InverseIndex[i]].

Answer (score 2):

In Python3:

```
import random
import numpy as np

def shuffle_forward(l):
    order = list(range(len(l)); random.shuffle(order))
    return list(np.array(l)[order]), order

def shuffle_backward(l, order):
    l_out = [0] * len(l)
    for i, j in enumerate(order):
        l_out[j] = l[i]
    return l_out
```