# select random indices from 2d array

Tags: python, multidimensional-array, random

I want to generate a 2d random array and select some`(m)` random indices to alter their values by predefined values`(m)`.

For an example here, I want to generate `4 by 4` matrix. Then select `4` random indices and alter their values with `[105,110,115,120]` this values.

```py
random_matrix = np.random.randint(0,100,(4,4))

# array([[27, 20,  2,  8],
#        [43, 88, 14, 63],
#        [ 5, 55,  4, 72],
#        [59, 49, 84, 96]])
```

Now, I want to randomly select `4` indices and alter their values from predefined `p_array = [105,110,115,120]`

I try to generate all the indices like this:

```py
[
    (i,j)
    for i in range(len(random_matrix)) 
    for j in range(len(random_matrix[i])) 
]
```

But how to select `4` random indices from this and alter their values from predefined `p_matrix`? I couldn't think of any solution because I have to ensure `4` unique random indices where I stuck badly, as randomness haven't that guarantee.

Can we generate random matrix and selecting indices in a single shot? I need that because if the size of `m` getting larger and larger than it will be getting slower (current implementation). I have to ensure performance also.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do the following:

```
import numpy as np

# for reproducibility
np.random.seed(42)

rows, cols = 4, 4
p_array = np.array([105, 110, 115, 120])

# generate random matrix that will always include all the values from p_array
k = rows * cols - len(p_array)
random_matrix = np.concatenate((p_array, np.random.randint(0, 100, k)))
np.random.shuffle(random_matrix)

random_matrix = random_matrix.reshape((rows, cols))
print(random_matrix)
```

**Output**

```
[[115  33  54  27]
 [  3  27  16  69]
 [ 33  24  81 105]
 [ 62 110  94 120]]
```

**UPDATE**

Assuming the same setup as before, you could do the following, to generate a random matrix knowing the indices of the `p_array` values:

```
positions = np.random.permutation(np.arange(rows * cols))
random_matrix = random_matrix[positions].reshape((rows, cols))
print("random-matrix")
print("-------------")
print(random_matrix)
print("-------------")

# get indices in flat array
flat_indices = np.argwhere(np.isin(positions, np.arange(4))).flatten()

# get indices in matrix
matrix_indices = np.unravel_index(flat_indices, (rows, cols))
print("p_array-indices")
print("-------------")
print(matrix_indices)

# verify that indeed those are the values
print(random_matrix[matrix_indices])
```

**Output**

```
random-matrix
-------------
[[ 60  74  20  14]
 [105  86 120  82]
 [ 74  87 110  51]
 [ 92 115  99  71]]
-------------
p_array-indices
-------------
(array([1, 1, 2, 3]), array([0, 2, 2, 1]))
[105 120 110 115]
```

Comment: Aha, thanks(+1) @DaniMesejo. I wasn't aware of `np.concatenate` by this style. I was new to python. Could you suggest me how to learn python in advanced (most probably data structure based)?

Comment: @WhyMeasureTheory Glad I could help! I enjoy watching the Pycon, EuroPython videos and reading the most voted/frequent SO questions. As for books Fluent Python is the first that comes to mind, also High Performance Python

Comment: Can I reverse the shuffle of that random_matrix?, @DaniMesejo. I was curious, that's why ask because by seeding like `np.random.seed(42)` I hope the reverse can be founded. Could you help me with that?

Comment: What you are saying is that you want to know the positions of the values of p_array right?

Comment: No, I want back my `p_array` from `random_matrix`. Like if someone gave me the `random_matrix` and told the seed, can it be possible to retrieve the `p_array`? @DaniMesejo

Comment: For clarity, I was inspired from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69010915/13053656). And wondering if it is possible to apply my case.  @DaniMesejo

Comment: @WhyMeasureTheory I think that is not possible

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/238559/discussion-between-whymeasuretheory-and-dani-mesejo).

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following, using your suggested cross-product and `random.sample`:

```
import random
from itertools import product

pool = [*product(range(len(random_matrix)), range(len(random_matrix[0])))]

random_indices = random.sample(pool, 4)
# [(3, 1), (1, 2), (2, 0), (2, 3)]
```