# (Python) Insert multiple elements into a list at different positions

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, image, scramble

I'm a student, I am working on a personal project which deals with images.
basically, I'm trying to make my own image scrambler, first I convert an image into 1D array of rgb values of image.

then I send this list into this function which basically scrambles the values of list (recursively), and is also reversible:

```py
def split_and_flip(array:list) -> list:
    """
    divides the list into 2 halves and flips each half, joins the flipped halves and returns single list
    does the same thing with each half recursively if the list contains even number of items, 
    because array with odd number items cannot be split and obtained back in original form.
    where as arary with even number items can be split recursively and can be obtained back
    as original form of array.

    :param array: list
    :return: list - modified
    """
    size = len(array)
    halfsize_int = size // 2
    h1 = array[:halfsize_int]
    h2 = array[halfsize_int:]
    s1 = halfsize_int
    s2 = size - halfsize_int
    # first half
    if s1%2==0:
        h1 = split_and_flip(h1)
    # second half
    if s2%2==0:
        h2 = split_and_flip(h2)
    return h1[::-1] + h2[::-1]
```

but, as you can see, if the list is having odd numbers of values, the scrambling and unscrambling won't be possible. or atleast, scrambling won't be as good.
to solve this problem, I came up with this idea:

To Scramble the image:

1. Add dummy values into the list until the size of the list becomes 2^n
2. use `split_and_flip(array)` on this array.
3. remove all the dummy values from the scrambled array.
4. convert the scrambled array back to image.

To Unscrambling the image :

1. make a `new_array` and do the steps 1 and 2 from above on the new array.
2. now know all the locations where dummy values end up, store the indices of dummy values in a list `indices`
3. insert the dummy values in the array at `indices`, call it `array`. (I am doing this step in order to obtain back the original unscrambled array of image)
4. now use `split_and_flip(array)`
5. remove all the dummy values.
6. convert this array to image.

We now have successfully unscrambled the image.
but while doing this, I came across this problem:

the problem I'm getting is in step 3 of unscrambling the image.
I have a list `array`, and another list `indices` which consists of integers. and some value `val` .
I want to insert the `val` in `arr` at different indices, and these indices are stored in `indices`.

is there a function which can do this job quickly?

I tried this code:

```py
def insert_values(array,indices,val):
    for index in indices:
        array.insert(index,value)
    return array
```

This code works, but I'm working with large arrays and there can be ***way too many*** insertions to be done depending on size of the image,
so.. my method is taking a **LOT** of time.

I came up with this idea of scrambling myself (idk if this is already done by someone else or not). that's why I am committed to making this work.

is there any faster way of doing this? perhaps using some library like numpy or pandas?
(I googled, but I didn't find the solution for this specific problem)
or is there any other approach for scrambling that I can take? (I really wanna do my idea though)

Comment: "if the list is having odd numbers of values, the scrambling and unscrambling won't be possible. or atleast, scrambling won't be as good." - Well, yes; you deliberately put code that skips making a recursive call if the size of a given array half is odd. Can you think of another possibility for the base case? Anyway, the question doesn't seem to be about writing the code, but about coming up with the logical steps for it to follow.

Comment: If it's just a plain list, you can call `random.shuffle()` on it, and avoid all this code.

Comment: @JohnGordon OP seems to want the permutation to be reversible.

Comment: Perhaps this question on [reversible shuffling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26577517/inverse-of-random-shuffle) can help. I haven't tested the codes in the answers to verify them though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simpler option would be to use `random.shuffle` with a known `seed`, and then 'unshuffle' the list later using the same seed.

The following program should do what you want:

```
import random

def shuffle(data, seed):
    # Take a copy of data
    shuffled = data[:]
    # Set the new random seed
    random.seed(seed)
    # shuffle the data
    random.shuffle(shuffled)
    # reset the seed (to avoid problems using random elsewhere)
    random.seed()
    return shuffled

def unshuffle(shuffled, seed):
    # Make a list of numbers the same length as the shuffled data
    index = list(range(len(shuffled)))
    # Shuffle this list using the same seed
    index_shuffled = shuffle(index, seed)
    # Zip the shuffled data and index together
    unshuffled = list(zip(shuffled, index_shuffled))
    # Sort the pairs to unshuffle them, and return a list of just the data values
    return [x for x, y in sorted(unshuffled, key=lambda x: x[1])]

if __name__ == "__main__":
    seed = 123
    data = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']

    print(data)
    shuf = shuffle(data, seed)
    print(shuf)
    unshuf = unshuffle(shuf, seed)
    print(unshuf)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I kinda feel stupid now for taking so much complicated approach. I didn't know that we can set our own seed. this is very simple and easy to understand. this is exactly what I wanted.